# Помогите задать параметр в def myname():

Tags: python, tkinter

Имею пример:

```
self.m = Menu(self.c, tearoff=0)
self.m["bg"] = 'white'
self.m["activebackground"] = 'gray'
```

как мне задать параметры, для функции `def myname():`,
 таким образом чтобы я мог читать вызывая `self.myname["bg"]`
 и изменять вызывая `self.myname["bg"] = 'white'`

Псевдокод:

```
myname = self.myname()
myname['bg'] = 'gray'

def myname(self, bg):
    self.bg = bg
    print(self.bg)
```

Нашел информацию о Menu в файле `__init__.py` tkinter:

```
class Menu(Widget):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'menu', cnf, kw)
...
    def add(self, itemType, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Internal function."""
        self.tk.call((self._w, 'add', itemType) +
                 self._options(cnf, kw))
```

Подскажите как работает словарь `cnf={}` ???
Нашел еще кое что:

```
class BaseWidget(Misc):
...
    def __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf={}, kw={}, extra=()):
        """Construct a widget with the parent widget MASTER, a name WIDGETNAME
        and appropriate options."""
        if kw:
            cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
        self.widgetName = widgetName
        BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
        if self._tclCommands is None:
            self._tclCommands = []
        classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
        for k, v in classes:
            del cnf[k]
        self.tk.call(
            (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
        for k, v in classes:
            k.configure(self, v)
```

Comment: Речь про доступ к локальным переменным функции извне или про что? Приведите псевдокод программы, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @ dIm0n, добавил псевдокод

Comment: добавил информацию, уточнение вопроса.

Comment: @biomotor вообще ничего не понятно. Давайте начнем сначала, какой вообще результат вы хотите получить? Не в плане кода, а в плане изменений графического интерфейса.

Comment: Если это продолжение вопроса про border меню - то скорее всего никак его не изменить, разве что меняя общесистемную тему оформления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с использованием класса:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dict_ = kwargs
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.dict_[key] = value
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dict_[key]
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.dict_)
x = MyClass(bg = "gray")

x["bg"] = "white"
print(x["bg"])
print(x)
```

вывод:

> `white`

> `{"bg": "white"}`

Comment: преследую другую цель... изменение конкретного параметра в функции, не вызывая функции со всеми параметрами.

Comment: @biomotor а чем вам классы не понравились?

Comment: это классы а это функции... хотел узнать есть ли возможность?

Comment: а есть ли возможность сделать еще  `def __getitem__` ? чтобы читать не `x.dict_`, а `x["bg"]`

Comment: добавьте в ответ (можно исправить), `def __getitem__(self, key):` `out = self.dict_[key]` `return out`